# AWS OpenSearch Service connection with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, nestjs, aws-elasticsearch, aws-documentdb-mongoapi

Is there any way we can connect AWS OpenSearch with MongoDB without using DocumentDb? I have an application based on Nest.js and ReactJs where I want to use OpenSearch Service